# Frame change of table view cell's subview won't take place until view did appear

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, frame, viewdidappear

I want to change a `UITableViewCell`'s subview when it is being setup in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following code:

```
cellSubView.center = CGPointZero
```

Printing out the frame's coordinates shows, that the frame updates successfully, however the view is still displayed in the position that was given in the interface builder.

Overriding the `viewDidAppear` function with the following code would resolve this issue:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But this will result in blinking: the table view already did appear when I change one of its cells' subview's position.

How is it possible to change the frame **before** the view did appear?

Comment: did you use AutoLayout?

Comment: If you are using autoLayout then try to reload the table in the viewWillLayoutSubviews() Delegate method.

Comment: From iOS8, you are not really supposed to adjust the frame in code. Code changes to frames from iOS8 often get ignored or changed by the constraints the system adds for you. Instead you should use constraints. Add a constraint for the `cellSubView` which centers it in its container view.

Comment: Why didn't you put it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used autoLayout check if it's creating the constraints automatically.
If yes, then you can change the constants of these constraints instead.
If you are not using autoLayout, call layoutIfNeeded and see if that changes anything.
My bet though is on autoLayout creating constraints automatically.